# How to disable past time in react js using react date picker

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Please guide me how can i disable past time in react JS. Below I am sharing code?

```
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import setHours from "date-fns/setHours";
import setMinutes from "date-fns/setMinutes";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";

<DatePicker selected={startDates} onChange={(date) => setStartDates(date)} showTimeSelect
excludeTimes={[
setHours(setMinutes(new Date(), 0), new Date().getHours())]} dateFormat="MMMM d, yyyy h:mm aa" />
```

Comment: minDate or minTime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want

```
<DatePicker
  selected={startDates}
  onChange={(date) => setStartDates(date)}
  showTimeSelect
  minDate={new Date()} //set the current date to disable past date
  minTime={new Date().getTime()} //set current time to disable past time
  maxTime={setHours(setMinutes(new Date(), 59), 23)} //this set the max time (i.e. 23:59)
  dateFormat="MMMM d, yyyy h:mm aa"
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

yeah as per the comment above you can use [minDate](https://reactdatepicker.com/#example-date-range-with-disabled-navigation-shown)

```
<DatePicker
  selected={startDate}
  onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
  {... otherProps}
  minDate={new Date()} // This here is what we require
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
() => {
  const [startDate, setStartDate] = useState(
    setHours(setMinutes(new Date(), 30), 17)
  );
  return (
    <DatePicker
      selected={startDate}
      onChange={(date) => setStartDate(date)}
      showTimeSelect
      minTime={setHours(setMinutes(new Date(), 0), 17)}
      maxTime={setHours(setMinutes(new Date(), 30), 20)}
      dateFormat="MMMM d, yyyy h:mm aa"
    />
  );
};
```